# Can you advice how to fix this? Basically I did not understand this errors to fix it

Tags: ssis

> Code: 0xC001700A    Source:    Description: The version number in
>   the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than
>   current version number. End Error
>
> Error: 2017-03-13 12:33:26.74    Code: 0xC0016020    Source:
>   Description: Package migration from version 8 to version 3 failed with
>   error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The
>   version number cannot be greater than current version number.". End
>   Error  Description: Error loading value "
>   S:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8" from node
>   "DTS:Property". End Error
>
> Could not load package "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Email\Email\bin\Deployment\ScriptSO.dtsx" because of
>   error 0xC0010014. Description: The package failed to load due to error
>   0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific
>   errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors.
>   This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter
>   errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

I created a ssis package and I was able to create and email a report in excel format in it.I received this errors when I executed dtexec /f "filepath\filename.dtsx" .Kindly help me.

I am using Visual Studio 2015,Sql server Data Tools for VS 2015,SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a package targetting a version of SQL Server which is later than 2008 R2, and it cannot be deployed to 2008 R2. From the sound of it, your package targets SQL Server 2014, given that version number 8 is mentioned. This blog https://sqlstudies.com/2015/04/27/what-sql-version-is-my-ssis-package/ lists the version numbers, and shows that version 3 is 2008 R2.

AFAIK, your only option is to drop back to using an earlier version of Visual Studio (I use Visual Studio 2008 when creating/editing packages for SQL Server 2008 R2).

You can choose which version of SQL Server to target when creating the package in the latest version of SSDT, but I believe that you can only go back to SQL Server 2012. This article has more info https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/

Comment: Is it possible to transfer my package to production server for which I need to change DB details and need to use task scheduler to run my package.

Comment: If your production server is running SQL Server 2014 then you won't have a version problem, so your package won't crash with the same error that you get when you run it locally. (However it is never a good idea to run anything in Production that you haven't tested elsewhere.)

Comment: My Production also 2008 R2 :(